# using NSURLConnection instead of stringWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, xml, delegates

Guys, I was retrieving an XML response from a .php script on my server using the following code:

```
 NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

and

```
//tried also: if(error)
if(!xmlString)
{
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download xml data (Error code %i )", [error code]];
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    [errorAlert release];
}

//*** now I have a touchXML xPath query code that extracts what I need from XML
```

My .php script wasn't working today and my iApp was freezing without any alerts, errors or notifications? I thought that the code above will handle errors but it doesn't???

A) Then what type of error does it catch?

Then I remembered that i I should try working with NSURLConnection and its delegate methods to catch any error that occurs.

```
//Inside viewDidLoad method        
NSMutableData *responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:self.chosenDrawRss] retain];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem I had using this approach was that app ran the Connection in the background and continued executing the rest of the code found in viewDidLoad, so I had to reorganize my code a bit by moving  it to another method that I call from delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading. The problem I have is that my delegate methods are not called. Well, all except *didFailWithError:* if I try to load URL that doesn't exist.

**UPDATE:** 
*delegate methods are called but it takes one minute or so for delegate method to be called and until alert message pops out...*

B) Could I use stringWithContentsOfURL and still have an alert to the user if anything happens?

<strike>C) If not, then I need help with setting up NSURLConnection approach? I mean, what I'm missing here is why aren't my delegate methods called?</strike>

I truly hope my questions make sense :D
L

Comment: Can you give your url if you can? I tried with a dummy url and i got the error.

Comment: Can you give your url if you can? I tried with a dummy url and i got the error when using stringWithContentsOfUrl

Answer (score 0):

If your delegate method is called in `didFailWithError` then i suppose it will even be called in
`connectionDidFinishLoading`. Check by enabling a breakpoint in the delegate methods and track the flow. It may have happened the function returns before you call the delegate.

```
NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

should be called in your delegate `connectionDidFinishLoading` method and in

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

I dont see why the alert should pop up after a minute unless you are doing some processing before displaying it.

Comment: I am sorry, it does fire didFailWithError and it shows the alert after minute or so :) If there is timeout to set that would be awesome... Now, the question about stringWithFormat still stays: when should we use it if it can't handle errors? I mean, Apple will not allow the application that gets stuck if URL is unavailable... Thanks... L

Comment: Does your delegate method do any other processing? NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] should be in your delegate methods and not where you are sending req as the req is async in nature.

Comment: It seem that one minute waiting is coming from server which has timeout for .php script set to 60-70 secs. Since this .php was grabbing XML from from a server that was down I got this delay of 1min. If I try to request for a URL that doesn't exist I get the alert message in a sec...
So to conclude the "first part": my app is working well with delegation and NSURLConnection, but I would still like to know when should I use the more convenient _stringWithContentsOfURL_ method if  error handling cannot be implemented in such a manner that Apple will say PASSED :) thank you for your comments